# How to solve TortoiseGitPlink Fatal Error?

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit, plink

I was using Git with beanstalk in windows 7. Now I got new system with Windows 8.1. Now I configured Git and Tortoisegit with new system.Its working fine in local commit but when I pushed to live I got error:

```
Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (Sever sent: public key)
```

I added SSH key and all? Is there any problem in Windows 8.1?
Thanks

Comment: Make sure your remote URL starts with "git@"

Comment: you might check if removing `core>tortoiseplink` block from `%userprofile%/.gitconfig` would help.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I opened **TortoiseGit > Settings > Network**
and in section **SSH client:** I changed `ssh.exe` instead of `TortoiseGitPlink.exe`.
Now it works fine.

Comment: _ssh.exe_ can be found in _C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin_.

Comment: _ssh.exe_ may also be found in _C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe_

Comment: In my case, this setting looks unchangeable at all. But there is one trick: one should re-install TortoiseGit and in the end of process (when installer will recommend you to make initial settings) select OpenSSH instead of TortoiseGitPlink.exe. This will give the required "ssh.exe" in the settings.

Comment: ssh.exe is asking for the key passphrase every time. Can I make it ask only after reboot? (So it behaves the same way like TortoiseGitPlink.exe.)

Comment: "use putty key" is disabled for me in tortoise clone when setting the path to the ssh.exe instead of tortoisegitplink.exe

Comment: There is no need to specify the full path to ssh.exe

Comment: another easy way to change this is in the Settings > General > click button "Re-run First Start Wizard" and then in the step 5 you can select e.g. "OpenSSH". No re-install needed.

Answer (score 13):

Or run Putty authentication agent (Pageant.exe) from TortoiseGit folder (usually C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin) and add PuttyKey manually to the app.

Answer (score 5):

This error indicates that the server requires public key authentication and no key was provided by the client.

TortoiseGit by default uses TortoiseGitPLink (which is based on Putty Link).

Therefore it requires key to be stored in the putty format and also

- configured in the putty session (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html) OR
- loaded in putty agent (this is done by TortoiseGit if loading ssh keys is enabled; can also be done manually by starting Putty authentication agent (can be found in the Startmenu or in TortoiseGit installation folder) and then loading your key; also other alternatives such as KeePass KeyAgent integrations exist).

You can, however, also use OpenSSH, by setting the SSH client to `ssh.exe` on TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Network if you have a OpenSSH key configured.

Comment: If Git command line tools are installed you can use `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`

Comment: There is no need for a full path as ssh.exe is on the `%path%` when called from TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 2):

On windows 8.1 and TortoiseGit 2.1.0.0, changing SSH Client to just "ssh.exe" solved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

check pageant.exe under C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin is running. and add key

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseGit may, from time to time, unload your putty key.

Simply open TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Git -> Remote

Then reload your putty key for your chosen remote connection (e.g. *origin*)

Answer (score 1):

For me this error was coming on windows 10.
It was giving this error due to different project name on my local than git repo.
After fresh clone it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because my key agent (KeePass KeyAgent plugin) didn't have the correct key loaded anymore. Added the correct key and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, configured Pageant key is removed. So, I added freshly.

TortoiseGit-> Select Pageant -> You can add your private key that was previously saved.

It worked for me.