# SVN RStudio Tortoise svn Crash

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, rstudio

I am trying to use version control for my data analysis projects although without the central server. I am trying to integrate Tortoise SVN with RStudio. I have set the global options and when I restart RStudio, it shows me the Tortoise SVN project commit monitor, I just press OK and wait for it to return to RSTudio but it does not. R takes forever to return and I end up killing the process after it becomes totally unresponsive. Am I doing something wrong with my installation or is this a bug in Tortoise svn? Has anyone faced this problem before and what did you do to fix it. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a great question for [RStudio Support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us).

Answer (score 1):

After reinstalling RStudio, the Tortoise SVN window would only appear if clicking on a pictogram in Windows 7's menu bar. After right-clicking Tortoise's pictogram from the menu bar and choosing "exit" a couple of times, R Studio opens normally.

Answer (score 1):

The TortoisSVN project monitor is a tool that resides in the background to monitor projects for changes. It never stops unless stopped manually. This happens if you just start the `TortoiseProc.exe` without any command line switches.

To use TortoiseSVN with specific commands/tasks, you have to pass some switches and info on the command line to `TortoiseProc.exe`.

See the docs on how to use those command line switches:
https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html

Answer (score 1):

I faced an error when I startup RStudio IDE.

[image: TortoiseGitPlink Fatal Error]

[image: The SVN setting]

I tried to find the solution online but there has no such application found when I search over my PC.

- [How to solve TortoiseGitPlink Fatal Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106717/how-to-solve-tortoisegitplink-fatal-error)

Finally I found the answer by checking the setting of SVN since above link advise me use SSH instead of TortoiseGitPlink. After that occasionally noticed below article and solved it. For SVN we need to use Silk-SVN instead of TortoiseGitPlink. Here is the solution : [Version Control with Git and SVN](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN).

- [TortoiseSVN inside RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200657436-TortoiseSVN-inside-RStudio-)

Comment: The second link you posted (TortoiseSVN inside RStudio) is behind a sign-in wall. If you have the chance can you update your post with some more info? I am trying to find a solution to use TortoiseSVN + RStudio. Thank you!