# pull failed by GUI TortoiseGit , however successfully by Git Bash

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I got the following error when using TortoiseGit, however I can run git pull successfully by the Git Bash with the command " git.exe pull --progress --no-rebase -v "origin"", what's should I config for TortoiseGit?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve TortoiseGitPlink Fatal Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106717/how-to-solve-tortoisegitplink-fatal-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git bash looks for an ssh private key in `%HOME%\.ssh` (with `HOME` being set by the git bash to `%USERPROFILE%`)

But for [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/), you need to specify that same private key in the settings (`Git/Remote`)
And/Or it uses putty: see " [Tips and tricks for SSH/PuTTY](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-faq.html)"

> Start PuTTY, go to Connection->SSH->Auth and select your key

In order for TortoiseGit to use ssh instead of putty, as the [OP Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6601466/jason) comments, you need to specify `ssh.exe` in the network settings.
That is true especially if you have generated ssh keys with openssh (`id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub`), and not with `puttygen` (`mykey.ppk`).

[image: http://guganeshan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Change-SSH-client-in-Network-options-of-TortoiseGit-Settings.png]

<sup>(Image from blog post "[Setting up Git and TortoiseGit with Bitbucket, step by step](http://guganeshan.com/blog/setting-up-git-and-tortoisegit-with-bitbucket-step-by-step.html)" by **[Guganeshan.T](https://twitter.com/guganeshan_t)**)</sup>

Comment: I solved the issue by the following URL
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106717/how-to-solve-tortoisegitplink-fatal-error

Comment: @Jason Great. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility