# TortoisePlink Fatal Error

Tags: ssh, tortoisehg

TortoisePlink Fatal Error Disconnected: No support authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

I found a similar post here that involved TortoiseGit.
[How to solve TortoiseGitPlink Fatal Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106717/how-to-solve-tortoisegitplink-fatal-error)

But the interface given in the top solution didn't match up with Tortoise HG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence for TortoiseHG was this:

TortoiseHG->Global Settings->Sync->SSH Command

Put ssh.exe in that slot.  Assuming you have all of the other ssh configurations set up correctly, that should get TortoiseHG working for you.

Comment: I have the same issue. Running TortoiseHg version 6.3.2 64bit and trying to interact with a local Gitea installation using public key authentication. Win10 PC. TortoiseHG->Global Settings->Sync->SSH Command was always "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\TortoisePlink.exe" Putting ssh.exe there, tries indefinitely to communicate with the server